# Help with understanding this proof about reflection in H. Friedman's axiomatization of set theory by Extensionality, Separation, and Reducibility?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

I saw this proof in Harvey Friedman [notes](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6a88ce1a88177132b084728eb6a7d99000d10b4b) titled THE AXIOMATIZATION OF SET THEORY BY EXTENSIONALITY, SEPARATION, AND REDUCIBILITY.

This a quote from page 5.

> LEMMA 1.2. Let $\varphi$ be a formula in $L(\in)$ whose free variables
> are among $x_1,…,x_n , n \geq  0$. let $\varphi^W$ be the result of
> relativizing all quantifiers to $W$. The following is provable in $\sf K(W)$. $$x_1,…,x_n \in W \to (\varphi\leftrightarrow \varphi^W)$$
> Proof: By induction on $\varphi$. It suffices to assume this is
> provable for $\varphi$ and to verify this is provable for $(\exists y)(\varphi)$. Let $x_1,…,x_n $ be such that all free variables of
> $(\exists y)(\varphi)$ are among $x_1,…,x_n $. Let $\varphi’$ be an
> alphabetic variant of $\varphi$ (i.e., change in bound variables) in
> which $x_{n+1}$ does not occur, and consider $\psi = (\exists z)(\varphi’[y/z])$. Then by RED and the induction hypothesis, $$\psi \leftrightarrow (\exists z \in W)(\varphi’[y/z])\leftrightarrow (\exists z \in W)(\varphi’[y/z]^W)\leftrightarrow (\exists z \in  W)(\varphi’^W[y/z])\leftrightarrow (\exists y \in W)(\varphi^W)\leftrightarrow (\exists y)(\varphi)^W$$
>
> as required. $\square$

I'm not understanding this proof. For instance $\varphi$ only has its free variables among symbols $x_1,..,x_n$, so it doesn't have the symbol $y$ free. Now the formula $(\exists y)(\varphi)$ doesn't seem to make sense, because $y$ doesn't occur free in $\varphi$.

Also I'm not getting the general plan of the proof? What he's really about to do? Why he is renaming the bound variables?

---

The theory $\sf K(W)$ Of Friedman is a theory written in first order logic with membership, and a constant symbol $W$. With the following axioms:

**Extensionality (EXT):** $(\forall z ) (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to (\forall z) (x \in z \leftrightarrow y \in z)$

**Subworld Separation (SS):**  $x \in W \to (\exists y \in W)(\forall z)(z \in y \leftrightarrow 
(z \in x \land \varphi))$, where $\varphi$ is a formula in $L(\in,W)$ in which $y$ is not free.

**Reducibility (RED):** $(x_1,..,x_n \in W \land  \varphi) \to (\exists y \in W)(\varphi)$ where $n \geq 0$, and $\varphi$ is a formula in $L (\in)$, whose free variables are among "$x_1,..,x_n,y$ "

Comment: Logicians often suppress variables in a formula, and so you should understand $\phi$ has free variable $y$. The proof is done by recursion on $\phi$, and the cases for boolean connectives ($\land$, $\lor$, $\to$) and the negation are easy to prove, so he only presented the proof for the existential quantifier that is most non-trivial.

Comment: @HanulJeon, Ok why he is renaming the bound variables? Still the proof is not that clear to me.